# Vim undofile does not work when file is too long

Tags: linux, vim

I use a vim persistent undo setup as follows, which have worked all that way here.

```
set undofile
set undodir=~/.vim/undodir
```

However now I'm facing a problem when the undofile became too long, notice that an undofile has a name in the form of absolute path like `%home%user%directory%...%directory%file` that means if your file has a big name, is under a big path directory or both, the chances for reaching the linux file name max length will be higher. In my case, when try to save the open file it raises the error:

```
E828: Cannot open undo file for writing: /home/user/.vim/undodir/%home%user%workspace%%app%javascript%packs%domains%components%grid%column_cell_factory%inspection_cell_factory.jsx
```

How can I manage in order to keep my persistent undo working even for these situations?

**UPDATE**

This is not my real filename, I removed username and others personal information intentionally, at the end they are not relevant and don't contain any special char. The file length is 160, and the whole path with the folder it should be stored is 189 length.

Comment: This whole path is just 138 characters though. What kind of filesystem has a problem with that?

Comment: @thatotherguy this is not the real path, I removed real username and others information. I will edit the question with the real length

Comment: The Linux limit generally is 255 bytes for the filename and 4096 for the path. Are you sure it's the length that's causing it to fail?

Comment: @thatotherguy unfortunately yes, I even tried another file with name only containing aaaaa 160 chars long, wich didn't work also, and got success with a 99 chars long, which created an undofile  143 chars long. Above this I got the same error. Other thing I also notice is that trying to create a file 144 chars long already opens it in readonly mode (in any other editor besides vim). Looks like the problem is with my SO that cannot save a so long. Any idea?

Comment: I tried get NAME_MAX setup and got 255 for `getconf NAME_MAX /`  however it is 143 for `getconf NAME_MAX ~/` and others folders below `$HOME`

Comment: I'm following the support from this ask also, https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/26751/vim-undofile-does-not-work-when-file-is-too-long?noredirect=1#comment47633_26751. And we found it might be my encrypted filesystem under HOME

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same problem, but luckily, there is a plugin to solve this problem:

https://github.com/pixelastic/vim-undodir-tree